# create activity inside fragment and Nothing happens when onListItemClick is called

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have the following code and 2 questions in the code Q1 and Q2

**Q1)** I have read on this site that you can't create a new Activity from inside a fragment, so if I'm inside a fragment and would like to do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

how do I do it?

---

**Q2)**
Also it seems like I don't get into my onListItemClick, am I'm doing something wrong here, is the OnListItemsClick missplaced or what?

I have the file ActionBarMain.java that creates a new fragment Fragment1.java bellow

//ActionbarMain.java

```
        fram1 = new FragMent1();
        fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
        fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");


//Fragment1.java
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class FragMent1 extends Fragment {

    private String[] bookNames;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        bookNames= bookNames();



        for (String str : bookNames)
            array.add(str);
        listView.setAdapter(array);
        return listView;
    }

    private String[] bookNames(){
        SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().count();
        bookNames = new String[SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().count()]; 
        for(int i=0; i < SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().count(); i++){
            bookNames[i]= SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().getBook(i).getTitle();
        }
        return bookNames;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Q1)Nothing happens here nothing is printed out and I get no errors when I click on
        //an Item in the list, its like it don't come here, why?
        Log.d("test", SimpleBookManager.getSimpleBookManager().getBook(position).getTitle());
        Log.d("test", "jje");

        //Q2)Call the DetailActivity.java how to achive this since I'm inside a fragment?   
    }
}
```

Comment: And where are you setting the longClickListener?

Comment: your questions seems a bit vague, it should have been 'starting an activity' instead of 'create activity'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a ListFragment ?

Something like this:

```
public class ListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.support.v4.app.ListFragment#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView
     * , android.view.View, int, long)
     */
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", item);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
} //END OF CLASS
//END OF FILE
```

The above code works for me.

Comment: What about the "fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");" it is now a listfragment and not a fragment how do I perform that in the "ActionBarMain.java?

Comment: The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragMent1, String)

Comment: Obvious that I forgot to set a listener, but setListAdapter(array); don't work

Comment: Ok it worked, so now to the other question, what about the first question, Doing "fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");" is now creating an error in Eclipse in the "ActionBarMain.java". Perhaps you have a solution to that aswell? =)

Answer (score 1):

A1)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActvity(), DetailActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

That will open the Detail Activity. `getActivity()` returns the activity on which your fragment is placed.

I will answer to your Q2 when I will get more info about the issue